# Insert javascript DIV in LI

Tags: javascript, html

i have a free html5 radio player and i need to add the song titles from a working javascript:

```
 <div id="track_name"></div>
```

("track_name" is generated by a java script function and work ok. Print: "Abba - Happy new year"

and i wanna to insert "track_name" in html5 player, here at ***PLACE*** :

```
 <li data-artist="PLACE" data-image="audios/test.jpg" data-live="true">
                <div class="amazingaudioplayer-source" data-src="http://music.com:8003/mp3.mp3" data-type="audio/mpeg" />
   </li>
```

both codes are in the same html page.

thanks for any help!

UPDATE, complet code:

this is index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Amazing HTML5 Audio Player, powered by http://amazingaudioplayer.com</title>

    <!-- Insert to your webpage before the </head> -->
    <script src="audioplayerengine/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="audioplayerengine/amazingaudioplayer.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="audioplayerengine/initaudioplayer-1.css">
    <script src="audioplayerengine/initaudioplayer-1.js"></script>
    <!-- End of head section HTML codes -->

</head>
<body>
<div style="margin:12px auto;">

    <!-- Insert to your webpage where you want to display the audio player -->
    <div id="amazingaudioplayer-1" style="display:block;position:relative;width:300px;height:164px;margin:0px auto 0px;">
        <ul class="amazingaudioplayer-audios" style="display:none;">

        <li data-artist=?????? data-image="audios/space.jpg" data-live="true">
                <div class="amazingaudioplayer-source" data-src="http://music:8005/mp3.mp3" data-type="audio/mpeg" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- End of body section HTML codes -->

</div>
</body>
```

and this is the javascript "track_name" function:

```
<div id="track_name"></div> 
                <script type="text/javascript">
        function UpdateTitle()
        { 
            var xmlhttp;
            //get "track name" block
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                {
                    var s = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    document.getElementById('track_name').innerHTML = s;
                }
            }
            //use random number in request to prevent caching
            var rand_no = Math.random();
            rand_no = rand_no * 100;
            //read the "temp_title.txt" file
            xmlhttp.open("POST", "/radio/temp_title.txt?"+rand_no, true);
            xmlhttp.send();     
        }   
        //
        setInterval("UpdateTitle()", 1000);
        UpdateTitle();
    </script>
```

Comment: you will need to show us the code you've done to export track_name

Comment: What does exporting here mean? Does this mean you want to insert the div into the li?

Comment: Welcome to community.please provide more explanation about your question and your target !

Answer (score 1):

Maybe ...

```
var trackNmae = "track_name";
document.getElementsByTag("li")[0].setAttribute("data-artist", trackName);
```

This will affect only the first `<li>` tag.

If the tag had an id, you could change it to be ...

HTML:

```
<li id="ID1" data-artist="PLACE" data-image="audios/test.jpg" data-live="true">
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("ID1").setAttribute("data-artist", trackName);
```

**UPDATE**:

Based on comments, this is my attempt at understanding.  Try ...

```
document.getElementById('track_name').innerHTML = s;
document.getElementsByTag("li")[0].setAttribute("data-artist", s);
```

**UPDATE 2**:

Change this code, as shown ...

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
    {
        var s = xmlhttp.responseText;
        document.getElementById('track_name').innerHTML = s;
        document.getElementsByTag("li")[0].setAttribute("data-artist", s); // CHANGE HERE!
    }
}
```

Comment: i added more details in frist post. data-artist="PLACE" that place must be = <div id="track_name"></div>

Comment: Are you looking to put what is inside the div, the "s" value of `.innerHTML = s` as the data-artist on the li?

Comment: i wanna to insert the "track_name" in <li data-artist="here"  somthing like: <li data-artist=track_name where track name is generated by the java function and works (example : "Abba - Happy new year"

Comment: Right, what I am getting is you are requesting the name "Abba ..." and this name is placed inside the `<div>` tag inside your `.onreadystatechange` function.  What I have put into the update is to also add that name into the attribute `data-artist` as something like `data-artist='Abba ...'`; Yes or no ... if no, please clarify where I am wrong.

Comment: <li id="ID1" data-artist="PLACE" data-image="audios/space.jpg" data-live="true"> this have output PLACE, what i need is song name, like "Abba - Happy new year", not the PLACE.....

Comment: in my html page, <div id="track_name"></div>  print a song name: "Abba - Happy new year"    and i wanna to replace the default code of html5 player <li data-artist="artist"> who print "artist" into html5 player, now i need to insert "track_name" into <li>. somthing like <li data-artist=$track_name>.

Comment: I think we are saying the same thing.  The variable `s` I referenced is the name, as far as I can tell from your code.  The line `document.getElementsByTag("li")[0].setAttribute("data-artist", s);` I generated will use s to change your li tag ... as the div name changes.

Comment: thanks so much for the help! sry for my english. but i really dont know java code, can u update the frist post again and tell me where to insert the java code?

Comment: See Update to ... for your information it is Javascript, not Java ... they are two completely different languages.

Comment: and the html line? <li id="ID1" data-artist="PLACE" data-image="audios/test.jpg" data-live="true">   this still print "PLACE"

Comment: In the code I inserted, PLACE will be replaced with the song name such as "Abba - Happy new year" (Best I can do tonight, got to get sleep for work tomorrow ... I'll check in through the day).

Comment: 5:36 am here. PLACE is printed instead of track_name.mby the html side must be a bit adjusted. i will go to sleep too. tkank you.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I also searched for the same thing but couldn't find a simple working solution so I have created one.

HTML PART:

```
<div class="table-container">
  <ul class="data-list">

  </ul>
</div>
```

JAVA SCRIPT:

```
const dataListRef = document.querySelector(".data-list");

//list item
var list = ["first", "second", "third"];

//render list item
var ul = document.querySelector("data-list");

list.forEach(item => {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerText = item;
  dataListRef.appendChild(li);
});
```

Some CSS to make it look better:

```
.table-container{
  width: 60%;
  margin:auto;
}
ul li{
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #454545;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

One can find the working solution [here codepen link](https://codepen.io/mukeshm280/pen/LYPMpEP)